# jQuery AJAX-request with JSON to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I try to send a JSON to PHP by using JQuery with AJAX.

But i always get the following errors:

```
jqXHR [object Object]
textStatusparsererror
errThrownSyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

My function:

```
function randomWithDB()
{
var data= arrayName[Math.floor(Math.random()*coktail_array.length)]; //gets a random value
$.ajax({
        url: "insertRandom.php",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({test: data}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(e) {
            location.reload()
        },
        error: function(e, t, o) {
            alert(data), console.log("jqXHR" + e + data), console.log("textStatus" + t), console.log("errThrown" + o)
        }
    });
}
```

And how do i retrieve the value of this JSON on the PHP side?

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname = 'mowe';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

    if(! $conn ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    }       
?>
```

Comment: `dataType: 'json'`  says the endpoint **must** return valid JSON.  If it is not, jQuery will get a parse error on the response and will go to the error handler.  Verify that you are returning valid JSON.  EDIT: And an empty response is not considered valid JSON either.  It must return some form of a JSON response.

Comment: We need to see how your php is building the output.

Comment: I have added the PHP code to the post above.

Comment: In addition to what @Taplar noted, any PHP warning printed before the JSON will also make it invalid. You should just check the data in DevTools.

Comment: when i used to use jquery, this would happen often. The easiest fix is to just switch the datatype to dataType: "text"

Comment: everyone is talking about how you return data, and that's definitely an issue, but I believe your question was about how to _send_ data? There are lots of tutorials and previous SO questions on the subject of sending JSON data to PHP via AJAX. Did you search for anything?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone, I find the mistake.

It should be:

```
var data = .....
var dataPost = {"za": data};
var dataString = JSON.stringify(dataPost);
.....
data: {myData: dataString},
```

Answer (score -4):

using jQuery for AJAX requests is obsolete, use XMLHttpRequest instead

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'insertRandom.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        location.reload();
    } else {  
       console.log("Error");  
    }  
};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({test: data}));
```

Comment: "using jQuery for AJAX requests is obsolete", is it personal opinion or are you basing it on actual stats?

Comment: @kidA why would you use a library for built in functionality of the language?

Comment: @dprogramz, for the same reason you might use any library in your project: speed up development time and not having to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: obsolete how?? jQuery is very popular and well supported and frequently updated. It's ajax functions in particular seem to be very frequently used. Nothing about it is obsolete. Please don't make opinionated statements as if they were fact.

Comment: I deleted my awnser since it seemed to offend too many jquery evangelists. I'll still to modern frameworks conversations. Have a good day

Comment: I agree that your specific statement regarding jQuery and AJAX is not well expressed. However, I would certainly agree that it's inappropriate to load jQuery (95KiB of minimized code), if the only thing you're wanting is slightly less verbose handling of AJAX requests.

Comment: @dprogramz 1. you haven't deleted your answer. There is a delete button if you wish to do so 2. No-one is being a jQuery "evangelist". Your statement regarding obsolescence is simply incorrect, that's all. If you can find some evidence to back up your assertion, I'll be happy to be proved wrong, but I doubt you will be able to. 3. No idea why you then mention "modern framework"? The code you've posted is just raw XHR, no framework needed. However almost every big framework ever published (not just JQuery) seems to come with its own wrapper round XHR, because the raw one is such a pain to use.